# using jade like rails templating?

Tags: pug, sails.js

I'm working on sails.js project using Jade (rather than EJS).

It seems like in EJS you can do something like this:

```
<div>
  <h1>My first view</h1>

  <h2>My corndog collection:</h2>
  <ul>
    <% _.each(corndogs, function (corndog) { %>
    <li><%= corndog.name %></li>
    <% }) %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can do something similar in Rails views.  How can I do this in sailjs using Jade, and send the data to the view like you do with instance variables/.erb files?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Jade, you can do the same:

```
ul
  each val, index in corndog
    li= val.name
```

Check out the documentation here for more ideas: http://jade-lang.com/reference/#iteration